# Why is this PHPUnit comparison wrong? ( .. $mock->with($this->identicalTo($foo) )

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have a problem with PhpUnit. I want to use the `isIdentical` method of PHPUnit to ensure that a method is called with a specific object as a parameter. 
Given is a mock object with method "setBar":

```
    $bar = new Bar();
    $someMock
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('setBar')
        ->with($this->identicalTo($bar));

    $someMock->setBar($bar);
```

This is of course only an example. It should work, but it doesn't. To get some hints, i  wrote some echo code in the `PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsIdentical` method:

```
public function evaluate($other, $description = '', $returnResult = FALSE)
{
    //...
    echo "\n";
    echo spl_object_hash($other) . "/". spl_object_hash($this->value). " - ". get_class($this->value) ."/". get_class($other);
    echo " ->> ";  
    var_dump($other === $this->value);
}
```

The object hash of `$other` is **not the same** as `$this->value` (while the hash of `$this->value` is actually the correct one)

**In the meantime, i found the reason for this error here. It's an issue of PHPUnit. Objects getting cloned by PHPUnit. I leave the question If someone knows a good workaround for this issue.**

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/41

Comment: what is the result of ```var_dump```?

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php "On the other hand, when using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class." I can't tell you why exactly it isn't working but if the method compares both objects using this operator, then it seems they aren't the same instance.

Comment: @bjauy Yeah. I get the wrong object $other as a parameter! This means, something probably goes wrong earlier. It's a little bit tricky to debug and find the place where this happens simply because many stuff is eval'd in PHPUnit (of course necessary here)
My first assumption was that an eval'd variable get a new hash anyway - but i checked that in a testscript and got good comparision